# Django Shell indexing Queryset on any position returns the exact same result - DB Lazy Evaluation

Tags: python, django, shell, django-queryset

This isn't maybe as much of a question as it is a **confirmation and request for more insight**.

When running a QuerySet request in python shell something like this:

`qs = MyModel.objects.all()` or `qs = MyModel.objects.get_queryset()` or `qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field='something')`

then followed by anything like this: `qs[0]` or `qs[1]` or `qs[any_valid_int]` it will always return the DB entry in position 0 of the returned QuerySet no matter what index you use. This mad me scratch my head at first. Now I understand QuerySets are generators in Django (?) and are **evaluated lazy** as documented here: [Django Doc: Querysets Are Lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

When you do anything (in the shell) that evaluates the returned `qs` like for example `len(qs)` and then use indexing again it will suddenly return the correct DB entries with `qs[any_valid_int]` behaving exactly as expected. I believe this corresponds with this [Django bug report question from 6 years ago](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26338) as well.

So am I on the right track here assuming that this has to do with lazy evaluation? And what is the **best/quick way in Django shell to just get a QuerySet and directly index the one you want** for testing without having to use something like `len(qs)` first? Is that even possible to use direct indexing like that or do you have iterate through them / filter the QuerySet further etc.? Thanks

Comment: If the queryset is not loaded yet, `qs[0]` will make a query to retrieve *that* item. But the database is free to return the records in any order possible (unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause of course), so it is possible that in the first query `qs[0]` indeed is the same as what is `qs[1]` in the second query.

Comment: Wow. fastest answer in history! Thanks. Hmmm very interesting! `order by` does indeed do the trick here. I've tried it at least with 10 indices and it always returns the same result. So this is part of lazy eval I suppose. Thanks for clarifying and getting back with an answer so fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So am I on the right track here assuming that this has to do with lazy evaluation?

**Yes**. If you have an *unevaluated* queryset `qs`, and you query with `qs[i]`, it will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT …
FROM …
WHERE …
LIMIT 1 OFFSET i
```

But if you do not specify a `ORDER BY …`, then the database can return records in any order, and thus the item at position `0` in the first query, can be at position 3 in the second query, which thus can result in the fact that `qs[0]` and `qs[1]` return the same item.

If you however use `len(qs)`, `list(qs)`, or anything that loads the data into the queryset, then `qs[0]` will *not* make an extra query to the database: it already has the records in the cache, so that means it will return the item at a specific location in the cache of the queryset, and since the records then have been returned in a certain order, regardless what that order is, `qs[0]` and `qs[1]` are thus different records returned by the database.